# Making a vertical nav bar strech out beyond its contents

Tags: html, css, navbar

I took this image from another post on here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zhnxa.jpg

I want the sidebar to have 100% height even when the sidebar items don't fit the height of the div

I've done float: left to the sidebar, so the content of the page that is more than the height of the sidebar is coming under the sidebar. Like this:https://i.stack.imgur.com/twdJe.jpg

So, basically, I want the sidebar to extend to the height of the page without having content underneath it if that makes sense.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/assassin/kmhmceL9/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach, where you can just fix the sidebar to the window using the CSS property `position:fixed`, this will set its position relative to the browser window, by setting `top:0px;bottom:0px;left:0px` it will be sticking to the left window and it will be full height always. Then we need to add a margin of `210px` to offset the content of the website so that it does not overlap the sidebar.

Note: I have used and additional CSS property called `box-sizing: border-box`, what this CSS property does is, it includes the border and padding of the element into the total height of the element, this is used because without it the border will cause a scrollbar when there is no content.

Let me know if the above code fixes your issue!

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content {
  margin-left: 210px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">this is the fixed sidebar</div>
<div class="content">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque et condimentum nibh. Aenean eu orci aliquam, consequat ipsum at, blandit eros. Duis commodo tincidunt ligula. Suspendisse pellentesque erat risus, pulvinar convallis ligula congue non.
  Nam sit amet tempus nisl. In malesuada at augue vel mattis. Sed luctus eu neque in dictum. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Proin pharetra tellus eu convallis suscipit. Mauris sit amet ultrices
  urna. Duis lectus nisl, luctus eu ultrices quis, scelerisque id lacus. Donec suscipit lacus sit amet accumsan consequat. Donec vitae sagittis risus. Sed at ante at sapien placerat laoreet a a leo. Integer tincidunt ut quam ornare luctus. Suspendisse
  sodales, ex quis congue laoreet, lacus tortor tristique metus, vitae tempus ipsum augue vitae lectus. Donec pharetra et metus at ultricies. Aliquam tempus gravida tortor. Mauris non finibus erat. Nam sed scelerisque metus. In pulvinar, lacus in placerat
  placerat, enim dolor porta magna, sed maximus enim felis nec tortor. Nunc elementum purus at justo dictum, quis mollis tellus vulputate. Maecenas sagittis placerat orci ac placerat. Nunc convallis sit amet nisi non imperdiet. Integer dictum ipsum nec
  nibh dapibus, ut consectetur mi hendrerit. Donec euismod, felis in luctus malesuada, est purus varius sapien, ut rhoncus mauris est a eros. Proin id metus eu quam aliquet pharetra. Nullam tincidunt ligula vel ligula consectetur eleifend. Proin non posuere
  libero. Etiam eu iaculis ex. Curabitur sit amet nibh interdum, elementum velit dictum, elementum purus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed bibendum sapien at imperdiet dictum. Phasellus congue
  et dui vel ultrices. Quisque felis risus, malesuada ac scelerisque et, vestibulum nec leo. Aenean eget enim vestibulum, vulputate dolor eu, scelerisque libero. In ut venenatis ligula, a vulputate eros. Maecenas eget convallis diam, non condimentum arcu.
  Mauris vitae velit in magna facilisis semper ut at lectus. Praesent tempor lorem nisl, eget finibus lorem lacinia id. Cras ac vulputate dui, sit amet pellentesque ante. Vestibulum mollis ante nec purus faucibus, ut mattis magna gravida. Aenean commodo
  velit non lorem hendrerit maximus. Sed nec urna convallis, mattis dolor eget, accumsan quam. Donec luctus, ante consectetur egestas aliquam, turpis turpis posuere enim, in convallis nunc massa et arcu. Fusce lobortis sapien orci, eu mollis sapien sollicitudin
  a. Ut semper iaculis malesuada. Fusce tincidunt lacinia justo quis faucibus. Aenean rutrum ex elit, in faucibus eros ultrices ut. Integer eu sagittis leo, et accumsan est. Aenean vel varius diam. Maecenas id tortor viverra, tristique massa non, consectetur
  velit. Pellentesque condimentum elit sed urna porta sollicitudin. Donec ultricies pellentesque diam, in mollis risus consequat eget. Donec a consectetur velit. Integer lobortis efficitur ante, eu sagittis nisl tincidunt et. Donec a neque scelerisque,
  pellentesque dui sed, feugiat tortor.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque et condimentum nibh. Aenean eu orci aliquam, consequat ipsum at, blandit eros. Duis commodo tincidunt ligula. Suspendisse pellentesque erat risus,
  pulvinar convallis ligula congue non. Nam sit amet tempus nisl. In malesuada at augue vel mattis. Sed luctus eu neque in dictum. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Proin pharetra tellus eu convallis
  suscipit. Mauris sit amet ultrices urna. Duis lectus nisl, luctus eu ultrices quis, scelerisque id lacus. Donec suscipit lacus sit amet accumsan consequat. Donec vitae sagittis risus. Sed at ante at sapien placerat laoreet a a leo. Integer tincidunt
  ut quam ornare luctus. Suspendisse sodales, ex quis congue laoreet, lacus tortor tristique metus, vitae tempus ipsum augue vitae lectus. Donec pharetra et metus at ultricies. Aliquam tempus gravida tortor. Mauris non finibus erat. Nam sed scelerisque
  metus. In pulvinar, lacus in placerat placerat, enim dolor porta magna, sed maximus enim felis nec tortor. Nunc elementum purus at justo dictum, quis mollis tellus vulputate. Maecenas sagittis placerat orci ac placerat. Nunc convallis sit amet nisi
  non imperdiet. Integer dictum ipsum nec nibh dapibus, ut consectetur mi hendrerit. Donec euismod, felis in luctus malesuada, est purus varius sapien, ut rhoncus mauris est a eros. Proin id metus eu quam aliquet pharetra. Nullam tincidunt ligula vel
  ligula consectetur eleifend. Proin non posuere libero. Etiam eu iaculis ex. Curabitur sit amet nibh interdum, elementum velit dictum, elementum purus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed bibendum
  sapien at imperdiet dictum. Phasellus congue et dui vel ultrices. Quisque felis risus, malesuada ac scelerisque et, vestibulum nec leo. Aenean eget enim vestibulum, vulputate dolor eu, scelerisque libero. In ut venenatis ligula, a vulputate eros. Maecenas
  eget convallis diam, non condimentum arcu. Mauris vitae velit in magna facilisis semper ut at lectus. Praesent tempor lorem nisl, eget finibus lorem lacinia id. Cras ac vulputate dui, sit amet pellentesque ante. Vestibulum mollis ante nec purus faucibus,
  ut mattis magna gravida. Aenean commodo velit non lorem hendrerit maximus. Sed nec urna convallis, mattis dolor eget, accumsan quam. Donec luctus, ante consectetur egestas aliquam, turpis turpis posuere enim, in convallis nunc massa et arcu. Fusce lobortis
  sapien orci, eu mollis sapien sollicitudin a. Ut semper iaculis malesuada. Fusce tincidunt lacinia justo quis faucibus. Aenean rutrum ex elit, in faucibus eros ultrices ut. Integer eu sagittis leo, et accumsan est. Aenean vel varius diam. Maecenas id
  tortor viverra, tristique massa non, consectetur velit. Pellentesque condimentum elit sed urna porta sollicitudin. Donec ultricies pellentesque diam, in mollis risus consequat eget. Donec a consectetur velit. Integer lobortis efficitur ante, eu sagittis
  nisl tincidunt et. Donec a neque scelerisque, pellentesque dui sed, feugiat tortor.
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, your code ran perfectly. Just what I wanted, I made a minor adjustment to your code though, by putting overflow:auto it allowed more content in the sidebar. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

give both the div float left and specific width.

And give them min-height: 100vh